# Periodic solution of first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, gcd-and-lcm, periodic-functions

Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,  \mathbb{R}^n)$. We observe the ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$. Let $\Phi: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be its unique phase flow. We assume that for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $T>0$ we have that
$$
\Phi(n_1T, x_0) = \Phi(n_2T, x_0) = x_0.
$$
Is it then true that $\Phi(\mathrm{gcd}(n_1, n_2)T, x_0) = x_0$ ($\mathrm{gcd}$ is the greatest common divider) or even $\Phi(T, x_0) = x_0$?

I really believe that both are true... . If I can complete a period in $n_1T$ (let's assume that $n_2 > n_1$) then I can complete a period in $(n_2-n_1)T$. Is this correct and if yes, what exactly are the implications of this thought process?

Comment: Is this about $gcd(a,b)=gcd(b,a-b)$ as basis of the Euclidean algorithm? Or about the lattice property $n_1\Bbb Z+n_2\Bbb Z=gcd(n_1,n_2)\Bbb Z$?

Comment: I do not know any of these so any help would be appreciated